# PHP, Sort in alphabetical with one array with Letters

Tags: php

I have a code that I need to sort alphabetically, not the normal alphabet, but a specified one. We can see below :

```
$alphabetArray = ['t','w','h','z','k','d','f','v','c','j','x','l','r','n','q','m','g','p','s','b'];
```

i have this array with these letters , i need sort other array by these letters, in the other array i have this :

```
$wordsArray = [ "jhona", "eric", "caio", "noah ];
```

in the normal alphabet are A B C D E F G H ..
but in this exercise , i need sort like T W H Z K D F V C J X L R N Q M G P S B

anyone can help me pls, i try sort functions but idk how to do that.

Comment: We do not have a [mcve] here.   We don't know where `eric` belongs.  Unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array#usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for user defined sort with a callback.
Note: It's necessary to use `use` to have access to `$alphabetArray` in the callback.

**Explanation:** `usort` takes 2 parameter: First the array for sorting and second a callback-function for comparing 2 elements of the array. For this callback I used an anonymous function with 2 parameters (I take `$a` and `$b`, but you can use here what you want). Because I needed the `$alphabetArray` in this function and can't use a third parameter for this I used `use`to get access to this global variable inside the function.
For comparision the compiler compares allways 2 values from your array with this callback and sort them by the return-value:

- $a < $b needs -1 (or any other negative value)
- $a = $b needs 0
- $a > $b needs +1 (or any other positive value)

The comparison of the 2 values goes like this:

- Look for the first char (beginning from the left) if one value has a smaller/bigger value (by your alphabetic-order represented in the `$alphabetArray`).
- If so return the needed return value -1/+1.
- Otherwise continue with the next char.
- If one string is shorter then the other then stop and return 0 if both values are equal.
- Otherwise return -1/+1 so that the shorter string will be sorted before the other.

Here for playing http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/06c40db2ce233494df533fc5f1842d27f94ed003

```
$alphabetArray = ['t','w','h','z','k','d','f','v','c','j','x','l','r','n','q','m','g','p','s','b'];
$wordsArray = [ "jhona", "eric", "caio", "noah", "noaht", "caxa", "caa" ];

usort($wordsArray, function($a,$b) use($alphabetArray) {
    $len = min(strlen($a), strlen($b));
    for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        $aa = array_search($a[$i], $alphabetArray);
        $bb = array_search($b[$i], $alphabetArray);
        if ($aa < $bb) return -1;
        elseif ($aa > $bb) return 1;
    }
    if (strlen($a)===strlen($b)) return 0;
    else return (strlen($a) - strlen($b));
});

print_r($wordsArray);
```

Comment: Can you explain more this "Function($a , $b)" ??, thx  for your answer , u save my life <3

Comment: @Dark Astolfo - I added a explanation for the callback-function `function($a, $b) { ... }` above in my answer.

Comment: What happens when you `array_search()` for `a` (which is not found in the lookup array? Should that returned value be different from `t`?